# find-bug error String can't cast to Util.Map

Tags: java

find-bug shows String can't cast to util.Map

When run through the application getting correct result.
siteList looks [{site_id=47, site_code=a}, {site_id=48, site_code=ABC}, {site_id=49, site_code=ABCD}, {site_id=54, site_code=ABCE}, {site_id=1, site_code=FXGL}]

```
public static List<SitesDto> transformSites(List<String> siteList) {
                List<SitesDto> sitList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object object : siteList) {
                    Map row = (Map) object;----->showing error
                    final SitesDto site = new SitesDto();
                    String code = (String) row.get(SITE_CODE);
                    Object id = row.get(SITE_ID);
                    site.setSiteId(((Number) id).longValue());
                    site.setSiteCode(code);
                    sitList.add(site);
                }
                return sitList;
            }
```

find-bug shows String can't cast to util.Map

Comment: "When run through the application getting correct result" - what do you mean by that? What application? String have nothing to do with Map, how do you want for it to be cast automatically? The fact that the String looks like a map doesn't mean it can be cast just like that. You need to parse it and create the map manually

Comment: Now the elements of `siteList` are all String object, String can not cast to map. What exactly do you want to do? If the elements of `siteList` are actually Map, the type of the argument shall be `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Map` interface represents a mapping between a key and a value.
Where as, siteList is a collection of Strings (they are not key and value pairs which Map is expecting), so is the error String can't cast to util.Map.

The List passed in parameter should be of  `List<Map<String,Object>>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper key value format used in Maps"? Where would you find a definition of a "proper" format?

Comment: Ok, my bad! got mistaken with `{key:value}` format, given siteList  will work.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a method that accepts a `List<String>` argument. Since you say that the application runs without any apparent error, it would appear that the `siteList` argument is not actually a `List<String>` at all, but instead is a `List<Map>`. You should have got a findbugs warning somewhere else, probably in the method that calls `transformSites`, saying that you shouldn't be using raw types or that a `List<Map>` shouldn't be passed to a method that takes a `List<String>` argument. You should fix that first. You should also avoid using raw types: use `List<whatever>` instead of just `List`, and `Map<String, Number>` instead of just Map. Otherwise, you are making it easier to make errors.